# How do I set the width of a GWT Slider Widget

Tags: javascript, gwt, slider, smartgwt

I am using 3 vertical sliders (com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Slider) next to each other horizontally (like  | | | ) I can't seem to figure out how to set the width of them so I can get them closer together.  I have tried .setWidth property and some similar settings in the CSS file.  There are properties to set the width of the slider bar itself but not the overall size of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how close you want them but when you look with a tool like firebug you can see the composition of the widget and see that the label width collaborate to the total width of a slider (as other parts of the slider probably).
I did a test by using the method `slider.setLabelWidth(10);` and the overall width is changing.
Is it what you want. If not provide a bit of code.